# Writing a field of a JSON query to a file Angular

Tags: angular, api, text-files

I am writing an Angular app that takes data from an API in JSON format and writes specific fields from the JSON result to a file. For example, if the query results in

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Banana"},{"id":2,"name":"Apple"}, {"id":3,"name":"Orange"},{"id":4,"name":"Kiwi"},{"id":5,"name":"Strawberry"},{"id":6,"name":"Blueberry"},{"id":7,"name":"Tomato"}]
```

and I want to only put the name field into a text file, looking like this:

```
Banana

Apple

Orange

Kiwi

Strawberry

Blueberry

Tomato
```

How would I do that?

I understand how to query the API and write the entire query to the text file:
in my TypeScript file:

```
this.http.get(this.url, httpOptions).subscribe((response) => {
      this.response = response;
      const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.response)], { type: 'application/json' });
      this.fileURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))
    });
```

and in my HTML file:

```
<a [href]="fileURL" download="name.txt">Download File</a>
```

But I am stuck on filtering out the data and successfully writing that to a file. How would I do this?

Comment: You are able to get the JSON object as array ?

Comment: No. When I set this.response = response and check the type, it says the type is undefined. How do I get the JSON object as an array?

Comment: Use `console.log(response)` if the response isn't there problem must be with GET request or with the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let result = [{ "id": 1, "name": "Banana" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Apple" }, { "id": 3, "name": "Orange" }, { "id": 4, "name": "Kiwi" }, { "id": 5, "name": "Strawberry" }, { "id": 6, "name": "Blueberry" }, { "id": 7, "name": "Tomato" }];
let textToPut="";
result.forEach(elt => {
    textToPut+= elt.name+"\n"; // add element name and back to line 
});
console.log(textToPut);
// Then put textToPut in your file
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var names = [{"id":1,"name":"Banana"},{"id":2,"name":"Apple"}, {"id":3,"name":"Orange"},{"id":4,"name":"Kiwi"},{"id":5,"name":"Strawberry"},{"id":6,"name":"Blueberry"},{"id":7,"name":"Tomato"}].map(i => i.name);

console.log(names);
```